# Archive button grayed out in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10, xcode-scheme

Would you be able to help me understand the reason why Archive button is grayed out in Xcode?

[image: screenshot]

I have all developers profiles downloaded

[image: screenshot]

Device type set to iPhone 6

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMkmN.png]

And archive is checked in scheme.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66pRt.png]

Comment: Put `Generic iOS Device` instead of selecting a Simulator.

Comment: Thank you ! For some reason I thought device is needed. It works now

Answer (score 543, accepted):

**Answer valid through Xcode 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 and 12+**

---

**You can not archive,** because from target you have not selected **device** or **Generic iOS device** or **Any iOS Device** , still there is a simulator.

Nothing generic or wrong with Xcode 7. This happens with all Xcode versions.

---

- **Problem - Why archived button is grayed out?**

[image]

---

- **Solution - Why archived button is not grayed out?**

[image]

In Xcode 12 it is named **Any iOS Device**

[image: Xcode 12]

Comment: Good luck. @atx

Comment: I wish Xcode would leave the Archive option enabled, but give a useful message like "you must select generic...blah blah".  Or anything that would tell you why it won't actually do the archive.  I'm not a fan of disabled options, especially when the end result is a lot of searching for the same issue by many people (such as is the case here).  I had encountered this issue before and had to search again because I forgot why it was an issue before, lol

Comment: @VariousArtist True, hope such additions comes in next XCode versions.

Comment: Still valid in XCode 9.2. 

Comment: Yeah, I guess Mac app development can’t change menu options run time, but it can enable / disable option.

Comment: Worked like charm

Comment: Seems like generic.

Comment: I feel so dumb by looking at this. Anyone else? thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: @Machado me too

Comment: The option is now called `Any iOS Device (arm64)`

Comment: Still valid in XCode 12.4

Comment: I don't think Apple is hostile towards developers, I just think they're suffering the consequences of making iOS and macOS a gated ecosystem. XCode is a mess, no doubt about that.

Comment: @Hasya Thank you for adding the screenshots. That's what has not been obvious for me in related questions on this matter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Completely obvious, but I was still stumped until I read your answer, when it BECAME obvious! Saved me pulling my hair out, again. Xcode - fun every day! :-)